# Oracle: Select using compound key from subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

So here's the situation- our records use a compound key of name/date. I want to see all names that have performed 2 specific actions in a row, so I want to do something like

```
 select name from 
 (select name as n, date as d from table where action='action1'),
 (select name from table where name = n and date > d and action='action2' and rownum=1 order by date desc)
```

but it counts n and d as invalid identifiers. How can I get it to do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytical functions are perfect for this sort of thing.... disclaimer this is quick and dirty and the column names are a little misleading. LAG/LEAD are the options you want to play with

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd7b2/7

```
select name,thedate,theaction,prev_action,prev_date from 
 (
 select name,thedate,theaction,
 lag(theaction) over (partition by name order by thedate,theaction) as prev_action,
lag(thedate) over (partition by name order by thedate,theaction) as prev_date
from table1 
order by name,thedate,theaction
)
where theaction = 'action1' and prev_action = 'action2'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

One method might be:

```
SELECT
  a1.name
FROM
  (SELECT name, date FROM table WHERE action = 'action1') a1
JOIN
  (SELECT name, date FROM table WHERE action = 'action2') a2
  ON
  a2.name = a1.name
  AND
  a2.date > a1.date
```

If there can be more than one instance of each action for a single name, this might give you duplicates.  In this case, it might be sufficient to use `SELECT DISTINCT` to eliminate the dups.

Note that this doesn't mean that the two actions happened immediately one after the other, just that action2 happened sometime after action1.

Comment: He wants action in row. He doesnt want action1.5 to be between action1 and action2.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri yes, I saw that but from the fact that his actual query only required one to be after the other I thought that he might not have meant literally "in a row".  That's why I pointed out that my answer does not guarantee that there is no intervening action.

Comment: Yeah, I only want the next action directly, without intervening actions. However, a join might be a good idea. Thanks

Comment: You could modify the query above, adding a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` subquery to verify that there is no other action between action1 and action2.  There are certainly other approaches, for instance using analytic functions.